# sort return after for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get my data from an API and run it through for a loop to get all objects in the array. I save the data I need in a const value.

The output of getmatchdata() looks something like this

```
["kINGPINj", 17, 13, 4],["AtZe", 15, 22, 5],["AtZe", 20, 21, 8],["Vetements", 25, 26, 10]...
```

But, I really want the data from getmatchdata() to be put into one big array where it is filtered into each username.
Any ideas on how can achieve this and should I maybe use something else than for loop?

```
const matchlistResponse = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/match/get?_=&id=${id}`);
const matchlistResponsestats = await matchlistResponse.json();
let matchArray = matchlistResponsestats.players.length
async function getmatchdata() {

  for (var i = 0; i < matchArray; i++) {
    if(matchlistResponsestats.players[i].username === username) {
      const username = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].username
      const kills = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].kills
      const deaths = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].deaths
      const headshots = matchlistResponsestats.players[i].headshots
      return [username, kills, deaths, headshots]
    }
  }
}
let playerstats = await getmatchdata()
console.log(playerstats)
```

Edit:

I want the output to be like this

```
[
  {
    "kINGPINj": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "kills": 17,
        "deaths": 13,
        "headshots": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AtZe": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "kills": 15,
        "deaths": 22,
        "headshots": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "kills": 20,
        "deaths": 21,
        "headshots": 8
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Could you provide an output example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be well suited here.

**Chaining way:**

```
matchlistResponsestats.filter((item) => item.username === 
username)
.map((item) => {
    return {
      item.name: [{id: item.id, kills: item.kills, deaths: item.deaths, 
      headshots: item.headshots}]
   }
})
```

**Explanation**

1) `filter` will return the array of matching criteria (item.username === 
    username) to the map function

2) `map` will get the filtered array and return the array of objects in the desired format

**Normal way:**

```
let filteredArray = matchlistResponsestats.filter((item) => item.username === 
    username)

let desiredArray = filteredArray.map((item) => {
        return {
          item.name: [{id: item.id, kills: item.kills, deaths: item.deaths, 
          headshots: item.headshots}]
       }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zain Ul Abideen, but I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: matchlistResponsestats.filter is not a function
    at getmatchdata`. I think its beause I run everything under an async promise all. How can I fix that?

Comment: That's because either the `matchlistResponsestats` is null or not an array. filter and map works with array.

check what you are getting in `matchlistResponsestats`?

Comment: It comes out as an array e.g {id: 1861639, region_id: 0, country_id: 79, map_id: 4, flags: 1, …}

Comment: @HyggeHjørnet The response you have shared is not an array, please update the question with exact value of  `matchlistResponsestats`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [["kINGPINj", 17, 13, 4],["AtZe", 15, 22, 5],["AtZe", 20, 21, 8],["Vetements", 25, 26, 10]];

function storeByKey(input) {
  let map = {};
  for (let e of input)
  {
      if (map[e[0]] == undefined)
      {
          map[e[0]] = [[e[1], e[2], e[3]]];
      } else {
          map[e[0]].push([e[1], e[2], e[3]]);
      }
  }
  return map;
}

console.log(storeByKey(input));
```